# kafka crashing when migrating from redhat 7 to redhat 8

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, redhat

I am facing this issue when migrating from Redhat7 to Redhat8 and can't find out why ?
I checked the code and everything's fine!

```
configuring ...
starting ...
endpointUrl = opc.tcp://LBA:9681/POO.S2K/OPCUA/DataAccess
== Info:   Trying 10.119.0.247:8090...

== Info: TCP_NODELAY set

%2|1662467686.094|THREAD|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: Unable to create broker thread: Operation now in progress (115)
%3|1662467686.094|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: Unable to create broker thread: Operation now in progress (115)
nbdtmdp: /home/deploy/nbdtmdp/build/src/librdkafka/librdkafka-prefix/src/librdkafka/src/rdkafka_broker.c:4773: rd_kafka_broker_add_logical: Assertion `rkb && *"failed to create broker thread"' failed.
./nbdtmdp_start.sh: line 7: 110235 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./nbdtmdp ../config/nbdtmdpCfg.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

from the deep bug forest here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=439776

Solutions

1. Increase Server RAM by 50% / 1GB and re Try.
2. Reduce kafka resource footprint by changing CLI params
3. Are you root?(privileged user) and did you try on redhat8 rather than migrate from 7 -> 8

Update ur question by adding what commands u used and your approach + the environment/hardware specs as much info as possible. Try all solutions and comment difficulties, i will launch an AWS Server and try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Caught the same error message because of cgroup pids limits. Check your system/cgroup limits such as:

```
systemd:
Default Tasks Max=50000
Default LimitNOFILE=50000
Default Limit NPROC=50000

cgroup:
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids.max

kernel:
kernel.pid_max
```

don't forget to check your container runtime default limits, if you run your workload inside containers.